# Унификация проверки типов

Tags: c#, типы

**Есть следующий код:**

```
public abstract class PointBase
{
}

public class ProductPoint : PointBase
{
}

public class EmptyPoint : PointBase
{
}

...

public void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<PointBase> points)
{
    points.ForEach(DoSome);
}

public void DoSome(PointBase point)
{
    if (point is ProductPoint)
    {
        DoSomeForProductPoint((ProductPoint)point);
        return;
    }
    if (point is EmptyPoint)
    {
        DoSomeForEmptyPoint((EmptyPoint)point);
        return;
    }

    throw new Exception("An unknown implementation.");
}
```

Мест с таким type checking'ом несколько.

**Что хочется?**

1. Чтобы при добавлении нового наследника от PointBase среда разработки сама мне говорила какие места с type checking'ом мне нужно дополнить чтобы они работали с новым наследником.
2. Чтобы нельзя было скомпилировать код (ну или в крайнем случае прогнать удачно тесты) без дополнения всех мест с type checking'ом для нового наследника.

**Решения в лоб:**

1. Какой-то волшебный метод в базовом классе с примерно следующим содержанием:

   ```
   public static void DoSomeForDerived(
       PointBase p,
       Action<ProductPoint> a1,
       Action<EmptyPoint> a2)
   {
       if (point is ProductPoint)
       {
           a1((ProductPoint)point);
           return;
       }
       if (point is EmptyPoint)
       {
           a2((EmptyPoint)point);
           return;
       }

       throw new Exception("An unknown implementation.");
   }
   ```

И собственно вызывать этот метод каждый раз когда мне нужен какой-то type checking прокидывая в него экшены которые нужно выполнять для каждого типа наследников. С таким решением при добавлении нового наследника, например какого-нибудь "CodePoint : PointBase", и добавлением нового экшена в сигнатуру метода компилятор при следующем билде скажет мне что все прежние использования этого метода содержат неполный набор аргуметов. И я, разработчик, буду вынужден тем самым заимплементить логику работы с новым наследником во всех местах.

2. Рефлексия при тестировании. Все методы которые в аргументах содержат какой-либо упоминание о PointBase тестировать отталкиваясь от текущего количества наследников в сборке вытаскивая их с помошью рефлексии. Тут мне конечно необходимо чтобы у всех наследников был конструктор без параметров чтобы я мог создать их экземпляры и понапихать туда для теста. Без наличия такого конструктора задача сильно усложняется и перестает иметь всякий смысл из за затрат по времени.

Ни один из вариантов мне не нравится. Буду рад увидеть любые предложения.

Comment: По моему, вы пытаетесь изобрести заново полиморфизм. Какую задачу вы решаете таким странным образом?

Comment: @Mirdin Задача примерно следующая. Каждый Point описывает место хранения данных. А какой-нибудь метод Delete принимает список этих Point'ов и производит операцию удаления. В данном случае тут самым правильным решением будет визитер, как предложили в ответах ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо того, у вас в коде присутствует проверка типа (а это само по-себе проблема и вы её описываете) потенциально метод DoSome нарушает SRP. Я бы отделил операции `DoSomeForEmptyPoint` и `DoSomeForProductPoint` в отдельное место и сделал бы вызовы непосредственно из классов `ProductPoint` и `EmptyPoint` воспользовавшись паттерном [визитер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), например:

```
public interface IPointVisitor
{
    void Visit(ProductPoint productPoint);
    void Visit(EmptyPoint emptyPoint);
}

class PointVisitor : IPointVisitor
{
    public void Visit(ProductPoint productPoint)
    {
        // DoSomeForProductPoint 
    }

    public void Visit(EmptyPoint emptyPoint)
    {
        // DoSomeForEmptyPoint 
    }
}

public abstract class PointBase 
{ 
    public abstract void Accept(IPointVisitor visitor);
}

public class ProductPoint : PointBase
{
    public override void Accept(IPointVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class EmptyPoint : PointBase
{
    public override void Accept(IPointVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IPointVisitor visitor = new PointVisitor();
        ProductPoint point = new ProductPoint();

        point.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

Из минусов подхода, при появлении нового класса в иерархии вам придется переделывать интерфейс визитера. С другой стороны, у вас появится простой полиморфный способ расширения операций над этой иерархией.

Comment: Спасибо. Визитер подоходи как нельзя лучше.

Answer (score 4):

По моему, вы пытаетесь заново изобрести полиморфизм.

```
public abstract class PointBase
{
    public virtual void DoSome()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        //Если метод не реализован в наследнике будет исключение
    }
}

public class ProductPoint : PointBase
{
     public override void DoSome()
     {
         //что то делаем...
     }
}

public class EmptyPoint : PointBase
{
     public override void DoSome()
     {
         //что то делаем...
     }
}

public void SomeMethod(IEnumerable<PointBase> points)
{
     foreach (point in points)
     {
          point.DoSome();
     }
}
```

**З.Ы.** Если родительский класс определить как:

```
public abstract class PointBase
{
    public abstract void DoSome();
}
```

то, без переопределения данного метода в наследнике, вы получите ошибку, еще на этапе компиляции. Какой из этих методов будет удобнее, зависит собственно от вас, и от структуры вашего проекта.

Comment: Думаю, ещё лучше будет объявить метод `DoSome` абстрактным в `PointBase`. Тогда без его реализации в наследниках код вообще не будет компилироваться, чего и хочет автор.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да можно и так, но тут нужно посмотреть, что будет удобнее в конкретном случае, а конкретики в вопросе нет.